# command line argument to a javascript file that works on mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, command-line

I have a javascript file ( .js ) that works on MongoDB. I run the .js file as
mongo localhost:27017/dbname  myjsfile.js .

How can I send command line arguments while running this JavaScript file ? I want to send database name and collection name as command line argument.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are already setting the database in use as you connect via:

```bash
mongo localhost:27017/dbname
```

So it is now on database "dbname". That is carried through to the `db` variable. Which is just a placeholder for the "current" database object.

That means that anything in your "script":

```js
var results = db.collection.find().toArray();
```

For example is using the database you selected and the collection you named.

Need more? This is valid to:

```js
db["mycollection"].find();
```

It's just JavaScript to the shell.

if you want a collection to be set as a variable then do something like this:

```js
mongo localhost/mydb --eval "var users = db.users" myfile.js
```

Or otherwise just do that in you JavaScript file. You can test that by:

```js
mongo localhost/mydb --eval "var users = db.users" --shell
```

And in the shell you now have a variable `users` that is "aliased" to the `users` collection.

Comment: ur reply is not clear to me. you didnt clearly tell how can I pass the collection name as an command line arument.

Comment: @prashantas There is some more information. Does that make things clear?

Comment: I know --eval will work but it is different from passing a shell variable

Comment: @wayne And unnecessary. Why parse JSON and not just `load()` JavaScript. Plus, the question asked "from the command line" And your answer says, "no you cannot". Hence the comment.

Comment: agree on unnecessary to load() javascript rather than parse. I feel parse give you an opportunity to catch an error. agree you answer the part can pass commandline but --eval is not necessary the solution for  a number of usecase.

Answer (score 0):

cli argument no. But you can read a json file and parse it in your script.

```
// config.json - {"dbname":"dbname","collection":"mycollection"}
var args = JSON.parse(cat("config.json"));
```

Comment: Not true. Anything you set in a JavaScript file that is loaded will be evaluated. You can even use `load()` for additional files. But of course you can use `--eval` on the command line as I have demonstrated. Have a look and a try yourself.